# Python - how to return values of nested fields from documents in Mongodb?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb-query

I’m querying my Mongodb using Python3 via pymongo and I’m struggling to get specific nested fields in the response.

All "regular" fields are returned correctly but the nested ones are returned as None.

Here is an example of my dataset :

```
{
    "_id":"5a8595ef93ccdb0f2301cf58",
    "docnum":"DOC001",
    "idcustomer":"CLI1",
    "customername":"Ringo",
    "address":[
        {
            "streetno":"45, First Avenue",
            "cityzip":"10001 New York"
        }],
    "totals":[
        {
            "totnetamnt":66.18,
            "totgrossamnt":86.034
        }]
}
```

And here is a part of my python code :

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

db = client.my_database

def load_data(db):
    cursor_docs = db.my_data.find(
        {
        " docnum " : " DOC0017133"
        }, 
        {
        "idcustomer" : 1,
        "docnum" : 1,
        "customername" : 1,
        "address.streetno" : 1,
        "address.cityzip" : 1,
        "totals.totnetamnt" : 1,
        "totals.totgrossamnt" : 1,
        }
        );

    #getting fields per document
    for docs in cursor_docs:
        docnum = docs.get("docnum")
        custname = docs.get("customername")
        address1 = docs.get("address.streetno")
        address2 = docs.get("address.cityzip")
        netamount =  docs.get("totals.totnetamnt")
        grossamount =  docs.get("totals.totgrossamnt")

        #checking field values
        print('docnum : ' + str(docnum))
        print('custname : ' + str(custname))
        print('address1 : ' + str(address1))
        print('address2 : ' + str(address2))
        print('netamount : ' + str(netamount))
        print('grossamount : ' + str(grossamount))

load_data(db)
```

here is my *current* output with nested fields returned as None

```
docnum : DOC0017133
custname : Mary
address1 : None
address2 : None
netamount : None
grossamount : None
```

and here is my *expected* output with actual values for nested fields

```
docnum : DOC0017133
custname : Mary
address1 : 45, First Avenue
address2 : 10001 New York
netamount : 66.18
grossamount : 86.034
```

I've tried different solutions but I always get the nested fields being returned as None.

The point is : How could I return only the values of nested fields for **address** and **totals** (as shown on expected results above)?

Comment: Read the wiki before adding unrelated tags!